# How can I reorder meta tags?

Tags: 7, meta-tags

According to my client's requirement, I need to change the order of meta tags. The requirements are also to hide some of the meta tags.

The order requested is similar to the following one.

```
<Title>
<Description>
<keywords>
```

Is there a module to achieve this easily, do I need to edit the files of the Metatag module?

Comment: Could you tell WHY client wants that? Maybe there is a module satisfying his need, but if so, it can't be googled simply under "head reorder".

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I just don't see the purpose of such re-ordering. If it's elements in the Body then it's for SEO purposes, but nonetheless an interesting question. If you could tell us "why" then it'd be even more interesting.

Comment: Its purely for SEO purpose, he whats to remove them just to get site data up on the site, that would be easy for google to crawl.

Comment: What source claims that the order of the meta tags is of relevance to SEO? While there's not reason to not answer the question itself, it's valid enough, the implementation here just seems like a big waste of time. As doing-what-the-client-said so often is.

Answer (score 10):

To alter the order of specific meta tags, a [`hook_html_head_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_html_head_alter/7) implementation in your theme's template.php file would be your best bet:

```
function MYTHEME_html_head_alter(&$head_elements) {
  // Combined with the devel module this line will tell you what elements you have to work with
  dpm($head_elements);

  // Any you can just alter the weight like this
  $head_elements['module:key']['#weight'] = -1000;
  $head_elements['another_module:another_key']['#weight'] = -999;
}
```

Comment: It's only valid for 7 and up.

Comment: @Mołot Yep, as the OP requested...

Comment: My mistake - it was not tagged with 7 and I somehow missed it in title. Either way, your answer does not tell how to bump <title> to the top, so I'll leave mine in place.

Comment: @Clive thanks for the answer, can you please elaborate how can i get "['module:key']".

Comment: You need to inspect the `$head_elements` array to see what's in it...the `dpm()` method through the Devel module would be easiest as noted in the comments

Answer (score 6):

HTML head elements are defined in 2 places.

### First one, easiest to access, is your theme's `html.tpl.php`.

In Professional Theme relevant part looks like that:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
<?php print $head; ?>
<title><?php print $head_title; ?></title>
<?php print $styles; ?>
<?php print $scripts; ?>
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
</head>
```

So, here you can put title before other headers. It's wise to leave CSS and JS parts at the end, in the order specified.

### If you feel you need to reorder what's in `$head` variable,

it gets more tricky. This variable is generated by Drupal core, and then altered by modules and themes. Good thing, your theme will be the last accessing it.

For Drupal 6, in `template.php` define [THEMENAME__preprocess_page(&$variables)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7), and alter or reorder `$variables['header']` as you please. Keep in mind that it may break other modules, especially if you will remove things. Reordering is relatively safe, adding is usually safe, removal is risky.

For Drupal 7 see [answer by Clive](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/77230/how-to-reorder-meta-tags-in-drupal-7#77235). [THEMENAME__preprocess_page(&$variables)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7) would still work, but 7 provides more direct solution to your problem.